# Is there a way to load ng-repeat new items with a click handler?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

repeat to handle new posts to be displayed which are being pushed from firebase. I would like to show a notification on new message and let the user click a button "show new posts" to display the new ng-repeat items. Right now it displays it automatically without notifying the user. Is there a way to handle such functionality ?
Your help will be much appreciated

Comment: can you show us some of you code???

Answer (score 0):

This may be a way to deal with this Karthik, if I've understood your problem.

1. Make the data that you're binding to the ng-repeat a COPY of the data coming from the service/api etc.

   angular.copy(dataForNgRepeat, dataFromServer);
2. To show a notification, do that if the dataFromServer changes.
   $scope.$watch... etc.
3. The button logic needs to basically update dataForNgRepeat by copying the data from the server again. That way, they are decoupled but you update the data for the ng-repeat on demand.

Simple enough :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use, for example, `$interval` to regularly query the DB for new posts, then display a message if `amount of posts from DB > amount of posts in $scope`

Controller:

```
// Initial loading of posts
...


$scope.newPostsAvailable = false;

$interval(function() {
    $http.get("/whatever/you/need")
    .then(function(response) {
        if (response.length > $scope.amountOfPosts) {
            $scope.fetchedPosts = response;
            $scope.newPostsAvailable = true;
        };
    })
}, 10000);

$scope.loadNewPosts = function() {
    // load the new posts into your ng-repeat scope variable
    $scope.newPostsAvailable = false;
}
```

HTML:

```
<alert ng-show="newPostsAvailable" ng-click="loadNewPosts()" type="info">New posts available. Click to load...</alert>
<!-- Your ng-repeat here -->
```

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but since it has not been given as an option:
Use the limitTo filter with a dynamic value in the ng-repeat.

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | limitTo: displayLimit">
    {{item}}
</div>
<button 
    ng-if="items.length>displayLimit" 
    ng-click="displayLimit=items.length">
    Show New Items
</button>
```

The displayLimit is initially set to items.length. If *items* gets new content and therefor the *displayLimit* has a lower value than *items.length*, you show the user a button, which increases *displayLimit* variable to *items.legth*.